# In WSL How do I make root inherit Windows's $PATH?

Tags: path, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In WSL How do I make root inherit Windows's $PATH? like my non-root-user does?
here is my problem:

```bash
hans@DESKTOP-41ABH79:~/projects$ code test.txt
hans@DESKTOP-41ABH79:~/projects$ sudo code test.txt
sudo: code: command not found
hans@DESKTOP-41ABH79:~/projects$ bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux_2.0.14.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware Player/bin/:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/PHP:/mnt/c/ffmpeg/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC:/mnt/c/Users/hans/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Program Files/mitmproxy/bin:/snap/bin
hans@DESKTOP-41ABH79:~/projects$ sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
hans@DESKTOP-41ABH79:~/projects$ bash -c 'type code'
code is /mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
hans@DESKTOP-41ABH79:~/projects$ sudo bash -c 'type code'
bash: line 1: type: code: not found
```

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with "Windows's $PATH". The problem you are running into is that the `sudo` command by default, for security reasons, does not pass the user's env vars to the sudo target user (usually "root"). See the `sudo --preserve-env` (also `sudo -E`) option. See also the `man sudoers` man page -- specifically the "Command environment" section.

Comment: hmm nope, doesn't work for me: ```hans@DESKTOP-EE15SLU:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program(...); hans@DESKTOP-EE15SLU:~$ sudo --preserve-env bash
root@DESKTOP-EE15SLU:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin``` - sudo -E does not preserve the windows's $PATH (or as it's called in Windows, %PATH%)